# Как применить интерфейс к классу в typescript?

Tags: typescript

Есть интерфейс:

```
interface Helpers {
  props: HelpersProps;
  appConstants: AppConstants;

  log(data: string[]): boolean;
}
```

Есть класс:

```
class Helpers implements Helpers {
  constructor(props) {
    const { appConstants } = props;

    this.appConstants = appConstants;
  }

  log(...data) {
    ... Тут код.

    return true;
  }
}
```

Вопрос:

1)Почему `props` и `...data` имеют тип `any`? Implements влияет?

Я понимаю, что можно задать типы "по месту" `(log(...data: string[]) {)`, но для чего тогда интерфейс?

Comment: интерфейс нужен, чтобы проверить, что все указано правильно. `props` имеет тип `any` потому что ты не указал другой тип. Обрати внимание, что в интерфейсе нет конструктора, из которого мог бы вывестись тип. Так как `props` - это `any` , то и все что из него получается тоже будет `any`

Comment: Что-то до конца не пойму. Как указать тип для `props`, кроме как: `constructor(props: HelpersProps)` и нужен ли он (`props`) после такого в интерфейсе?

Comment: в интерфейсе указано поле `props`, которое в классе вообще отсутствует.

Comment: Кажется понимаю... А как описать конструктор в интерфейсе? И, насколько я понимаю, мне необходимо использовать в интерфейсе публичные поля, то есть `appConstants` из интерфейса убрать в класс, как: `private readonly appConstants: AppConstants;` верно?

Comment: интерфейс по определению - это только публичные методы и свойства.

Comment: Класс реализует интерйес (implements), а не интерфейс применяется к классу. Интерфейс задаёт контракт для какого-то места, где требуется использование объекта. Он вообще не для класса. Ваш класс сейчас не реализует интерфейс, если не считать, что any подходит для всего. А чтобы реализовал, нужно писать в классе соответствующие типы. Тогда он будет подходить под интерфейс, и соответственно под то место, где требуется объект с таким интерфейсом. И в таком месте никогда не требуется конструктор, поэтому его в интерфейсах нет.

Comment: [How does interfaces with construct signatures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13407036/2881286)

Comment: Спасибо. И последние два вопроса: 1) если я задаю для метода `log` тип возвращаемого значения `void`, я и в классе для `log` дублирую `void`, верно? 2)Класс имеет один публичный метод, нужно ли для него создавать интерфейс, для контракта?

Comment: 1) Если в интерфейсе написали void, значит в месте использования вам не важно, что возвращает метод. Соответственно можете писать любой возвращаемый тип в классе. 2) Нет. Нужно исходить из места использования. Если в этом месте нужен этот метод, то его следует добавить в интерфейс, а уже потом в класс. В классе могут быть методы, которых нет в интерфейсе, он не обязан ограничиваться только одним интерфейсом.

Comment: @Grundy ... здесь это так не работает

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, это ответ на какое сообщение? :-)

Comment: @Grundy __в интерфейсе указано поле props, которое в классе вообще отсутствует__(c) - это одноименный интерфейс, он не реализуется классом, а уже присутствует в классе. см. ответ

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg если подходить формально - объявлено поле, в классе его нет - все ок :) то, что при этом компилятор считает, что поле есть, тут уж куда деваться ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Представленный код абсолютно бесполезен(за некоторым исключением). TypeScript очень своеобразно обрабатывает ссылки на типы, ... и, по большому счету, для него не важно `type`|`interface`|`class`.

Попробуйте изменить имя интерфейса на `IHelpers`, [и сразу увидите ошибку неверной реализации](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAehAJCQQQGEEARBA4QaheEEEIg4CMwCWA7ALgKYBOAZgIYDGB4AEgQDYAOxAzuAN7DjiNED2jFgC5wAchJ8+o8AB8xAIzJFRXcPT4BzABQA6PQBMyeMiJZ4iuDQG0AugEoR8yfQJkcwAL7BgFemRZsdEys4FgAtowuYQT4gQzMRGyc3BR8OGZEAK4UeHxEWnYcql6q6tp6OobGpuaWtg7gTnwubkXc3EQEeJlEOOAAhP1VZDouOBp4ABbFnt5gUHCIqOAATNj4xORU4ACSQQlJqrwCwmISUrIKSircZboGRibgGXX2js6u7iW+-mwAynxovsQuFIgRorFdsDEm1wPNwAA9JHIlEI8AAHgAtOAkIBWEHAsFx0EA3CDwQDsIIA+EEATCDICngQCCIFSKYBOEHpKCZPH4glUqXS5myuXyhWS4BKt0090qjxqFnG9XezU+sI6XR6fUGw1GMQm024Xg8QA).
Попробуйте изменить ключевое слово `interface` на `type`, [...Ой, он вдруг стал интерфейсом](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEiQQQGEEARBA4QTC8IIIRBQGYBQAXAngBwKagCSAEvgDYEBOAzqALygDe6oouVA9rjQFygByAGadOA0AB9BAIwCGVAa1DlOAcwAUAOm0ATWZln8amKgEsAdqoDaAXQCU-aaPL5Z59AF906AMblZNHQAypwAtvhklPi0oKahuC7h5ph0pBTUdCxsIGwAevkFhbmgADwAtKAAwv6BgiHhkRniFj6cVFT4Ppjk2LHxifjJdBaY0UKyPoQCaVG0imyt5sZUAK5dbep2zEpeSioa2pp6BkYmFtb2js6u5ttsbB2YK1S3AISvx7KaLpaYABY7TxAA).

Одноименные интерфейсы и классы сообщают компилятору о смешивании типа:

```
// Декларируем одноименный интерфейс
interface Helpers {
  print(): void
}

class Helpers {
  log(): void {
    // ...
  }
}

const h = new Helpers()
h.log()
// Удивительное дело, метод не реализован, но присутствует в типе.
// TypeScript, при этом, не воспринимает это ошибкой.
h.print()
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEhQQRWEELhBG4QQGEEAIggOEEYYRBKB4QUg+EECwggvCA7KaQEGDSIIJwgoyBgQiCSKAiIJFYIIgAUAJYB2ALgFMATgDMAhgGNBoABKCANgAcRAZ1ABvTqFBLhffgAoAlAC5QANwD23ACacAvp06SF41evnK1m7aAVWAOYm5tZ2vjo6IKAAdHF+Tk4uVryq-KAAFqAAvKC8ggDucooqwqomnBkxAcHGnNGAxCB4yIBMIMiMsIAyIESQoHiQsDgANKCk9PigBL2IkPCwyIDsIDgt8AQjRKCA-CAo7Gj07PQtGPSgLaD0yJuQlTF6BiZAA)

Резюмируя можно сказать:
Одноименными интерфейсами мы сообщаем о наличии тех или иных свойств типа,
которые могут быть реализованы не в нашем коде, а сторонним движком/приложением. Собственно в файлах `lib.*.d.ts` и описаны интерфейсы стандартных типов JS.

PS: Кроме того, подобное поведение позволяет легко расширять библиотеку типов, когда файл `lib.2015.d.ts` расширяется `lib.2021.d.ts`.

PPS: ... а нам это может понадобится, для добавления кастомных свойств стандартным типам.